# In UNIX, what are the Ss, Sl, and Ssl proccess types I see with ps aux?

Tags: unix, process, ps

When doing a `ps aux` command, I see some process listed as `Ss`, `Ssl` and `Sl`.

What do these mean?

```
root     24653  0.0  0.0   2256     8 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:00 /bin/bash -c /usr/bin/python /var/python/report_watchman.py 
root     24654  0.0  0.0  74412    88 ?        Sl   Apr12   0:01 /usr/bin/python /var/python/report_watchman.py
root     21976  0.0  0.0   2256     8 ?        Ss   Apr14   0:00 /bin/bash -c /usr/bin/python /var/python/report_watchman.py 
root     21977  0.0  0.0  73628    88 ?        Sl   Apr14   0:01 /usr/bin/python /var/python/report_watchman.py
```

Comment: [ps aux output meaning](https://superuser.com/q/117913/623314)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

From the [ps manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html):

> ```
>    S    Interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
>
>   For BSD formats and when the stat keyword is used, additional
>   characters may be displayed:
>   s    is a session leader
>   l    is multi-threaded (using CLONE_THREAD, like NPTL pthreads do)
> ```

Comment: When in doubt, `man`!

Comment: A 10 years old question, but since it is the first google result for this question, I am updating the URL link for for the ps manpage: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?ps